# Google Sheets - Function that generates range reference based on 'base' and 'offset' values

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a function whose interface is the same as the `OFFSET` function but returns the range reference (i.e. A2:A20) instead of the actual range itself.

Below, I've outlined this imaginary `RANGE` function with how its used and expected results.

API: `RANGE(cell_reference, offset_rows, offset_columns, [height], [width])`

Usage:

`RANGE(A2, 0, 0, 18)` => `A2:A20`

`RANGE(A2, 0, 0, 18, 2)` => `A2:C20`

`RANGE(A2, 2)` => `C2`

`RANGE(A2, 0, 2)` => `A4`

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear why you would need to get a range address as a text string in the first place. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: I'm looking to create a dynamic data sheet that adjust criteria based on user input within one cell which will ultimately fall under an INDIRECT call. It's easy to use solve this problem through string concatenation but would by very difficult to debug, especially when I'm moving cell locations through actions such as copy-pasting. Using direct references to cells would allow Google Sheets to intelligently auto-update cell references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cell()`, like this:

`=cell("address", A2) & ":" & cell("address", offset(A2, 3, 2))`

The `cell()` function will include the sheet name when the reference is on another sheet. You can use `regexreplace()` to strip the sheet name from the latter reference if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! This was significantly cleaner then what I had come up with. Didn't know this existed, especially since I went through the functions list and it wasn't under type "Lookup", which I think it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying a couple of things and was able to sort of create this. Not looking too clean but it works.

`RANGE(A2, 0, 0, 18)` => `ADDRESS(ROW(A2), COLUMN(A2))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(A2)+18, COLUMN(A2))` => `A2:A20`

`RANGE(A2, 0, 0, 18, 2)` => `ADDRESS(ROW(A2), COLUMN(A2))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(A2)+18, COLUMN(A2)+2)` =>`A2:C20`

`RANGE(A2, 2)` => `ADDRESS(ROW(A2), COLUMN(A2)+2)` => `C2`

`RANGE(A2, 0, 2)` => `ADDRESS(ROW(A2)+2, COLUMN(A2))` => `A4`

However, this becomes difficult to work with when across multiple sheets. For example, `=ADDRESS(ROW(honing!A2), COLUMN(honing!A2),4,,"honing")` requires the static string "honing" in order to output `honing!A2`. Without it, it would output just `A2`.